# how to break recursive function

Tags: python, list, mongodb, recursion, instagram

I am using instagram API, and this is my code;

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
api = InstagramAPI(access_token='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
tagname = 'naturelover'

photo_urls = []

def get_urls( skeyword, next_max_id=None ):

    tags_recent_media, next = api.tag_recent_media( max_id=next_max_id, tag_name = "%s"%skeyword )
    if tags_recent_media:
        [photo_urls.append(media.images['standard_resolution'].url) for media in tags_recent_media]
        if next is None:
            pass
        else:
            if next.find('max_id') == -1:
                next_max_id = next.split('max_tag_id=')[1]
                next_page_id="%s"%next_max_id.split('&')[0]
            else:
                next_max_id = next.split('max_id=')[1]
                if next_max_id.split('&'):
                    next_page_id="%s"%next_max_id.split('&')[0]

            get_urls( skeyword, next_page_id )
    else:
        pass
    return photo_urls

tag_media_data = get_urls(tagname,inc)
mongo.insert({'media':tag_media_data})
```

On every single request instagram returns 2o max images, and a **next URL** for pagination, i am trying to store all images based on tag for this i have to call function recursively until **next url** is not none, here next is a url and i sliced it to fetch next url id (instagram api support next id for pagination). But I got a **max recursion call error**, searching for this error i got some answers like set value for stackrecursion but that doesn't make sense in terms of logic. I am not finding any solution on this for how to break recursion after some recursion calls or any other alternative way.

In the end of code, i saved all of list data in a single mongo document, other way i saved data after every recursion call by doing this i got redundant data in every document like this:

```
photo_urls = []
[photo_urls.append(media.images['standard_resolution'].url) for media in tags_recent_media]
mongo.insert({'media':photo_urls})
```

I couldn't find other way still, i am trying to do this in other way, please point out if this problem needs to be more descriptive.

Comment: Where does `nextcall` come from?

Comment: Also, can you show the full traceback? That might help.

Comment: @ChristianTernus: it was just a try, i tried to call other function here, by mistake it happens there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is always representable as an explicit loop. Consider this approach:

```
next_page_id = None
while True:
  tags_recent_media, next = api.tag_recent_media(keyword, next_page_id)
  extractImagesFrom(tags_recent_media)
  if not next:
    break
  next_page_id = ...
```

I bet it's the kind of code the API authors meant.

Comment: this is extractImagesFrom(tags_recent_media) for data storing purpose?

Comment: but for next id, i have to call function recursively

Comment: Yes, `extractImagesFrom(...)` is something that extracts and stores the images. No, you don't need recursion, you need the next loop ieration. Just follow the loop mentally (or with pen and paper).

Comment: Thanks, i need to be trust on loops...waste my time on recusrion!! thanks